# Single system to track status of all journal submissions?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

Is there a software or website where I can track the status Editorial Manager system for all, or most, of my journal submissions rather than logging into all of their websites individually?

As an example a website like mint.com tracks all my banks together.

Comment: No, there probably isn't. How many simultaneous submissions do you have that this is an issue? Usually, you'll receive emails if you need to access the system.

Comment: A nice problem to have.

Comment: If systems like ORCID exist to unify citations and all, such a system makes some sense as well.

Comment: @bissi, actually there are many journals today that support login via ORCID.

Comment: I found an almost complete answer in this website : Research Square. It seems to track almost all my Springer articles...

Answer (score 4):

There isn't. That isn't even possible in most cases if different journals use the same software system (say, between all Elsevier journals) and it certainly isn't possible for journals managed by different publishers.

Comment: "impossible" is too strong of a word here ;) I'm sure a few years ago someone would have said you cannot "compare" a literature journal with a quantum physics journal. probably some entrepreneur would take on this idea

Comment: @bissi I didn't say that it's "impossible". I just said that it isn't possible right now. "isn't possible" is not the same as "impossible".

Comment: I would say that it's technically possible right now (based on scraping of HTML pages), but the solution might be very fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically.  I do use a ticket tracker to keep track of these things manually.

A ticket tracker is also known as a bug tracker or an issue tracker.  The one I use is https://osticket.com/.  There are many.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

Comment: A what? The only thing a "ticket tracker" to me means the tags you'd get at an ice cream shop

Comment: please explain what's a ticket tracker

Comment: +1 for manual tracking. I use a Google Spreadsheet (comparable to PowerPoint) to emulate a virtual "wall with post-its": have a slide (a.k.a. "wall") with separate areas "in preparation", submitted, accepted" and move colorful boxes (a.k.a. "post-its" representing papers) between the areas.